# LINQ Lambda Join with Count

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'd like to get all teams without the current team and get all teams with 4 or more player.
I try to write this linq lambda query:

```
teams = connection.Team 
    .Join(connection.Player,
        t => t.ID,
        p => p.IDTeam,
        (t, p) => new { Team = t, Player = p })
    .Where(tp => tp.Player.IDTeam == tp.Team.ID
        && tp.Team.ID != team.ID
        && tp.Team.IsVisible == true
        && !tp.Team.DeleteDate.HasValue)
    .Select(tp => tp.Team)
    .ToList();
```

but I cannot count on where condition how many players have the teams. How to do? Which is, for info, the query in SQL?
Thanks for help!

EDIT:
As Required the classes (generate from DBFirst):
[image: No relation between the classes. The match is Team.ID == Player.IDTeam]

Comment: You don't have navigation properties?

Comment: Could you provide Player and Team classes?

Comment: @DarjanBogdan added.
No Tim, any nav properties
Thanks

Comment: @MicheleBoscagin: i'm pretty sure there is no foreign key on `Player.IdTeam` to `Team.Id`. Fix that and Entity-Framework will add this navigation property.

Answer (score 3):

Based on classes above, you can extend `Team` class and add `Players` navigational property.

When adding navigational property, make sure you have database relationship between *Team* and *Player* tables in place. Also, if needed configure your `DbContext`.

```
public class Team
{
    //...other properties
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

When you add navigational property, it will be trivial to achieve your requirement:

```
connection.Teams
          .Where(t => t.ID != team.ID && t.IsVisible == true && !t.DeleteDate.HasValue && t.Players.Count() >= 4)
```

Comment: I guess there were no foreign-keys, that's why entity framework didn't create automatically.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, probably that's it

Answer (score 0):

Try a GroupBy() :

```
var teams = (from tp in connection.Team
   join p in connection.Team on tp.Player.IDTeam equals p.Team.ID
   select new { Team = tp, Player = p })
   .Where(tp =>  tp.Team.IsVisible == true && !tp.Team.DeleteDate.HasValue)
   .GroupBy(x => x.Team.ID)
   .Where(x => x.Count >= 4)
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
teams = connection.Team 
.Join(connection.Player,
    t => t.ID,
    p => p.IDTeam,
    (t, p) => new { Team = t, Player = p })
.Where(tp => tp.Player.IDTeam == tp.Team.ID
    && tp.Team.ID != team.ID
    && tp.Team.IsVisible == true
    && !tp.Team.DeleteDate.HasValue)
.Select(tp => tp.Team)
.ToList().GroupBy(i=>i.ID).Where(i=>i.Count()>=4);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var teams = 
           (from t in connection.Team
           join p in connection.Player on p.TeamId equals t.ID into playersInTeam
           select new 
           { 
                Team = t, 
                PlayersCount = playersInTeam.Count(x => x.TeamId == t.Id) 
           })
           .Where(x => x.PlayersCount >= 4)
           .ToList();
```